# I want to redirect the page after photo upload

Tags: php, javascript, redirect, photo-upload

I am using the photoupload which is in the below link http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/
but i want to redirect the page after the upload is completed. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

here:

```
<?php
/* do something with the upload code..... */
/* Redirect browser */
header("Location: http://theos.in/");
/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var totalUploadCount = $('#fileUpload').length;
var completedCount = 0;


$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
                if(completedCount++ == totalUploadCount)
                    window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: i added this in main.js but only single photo is uploaded not multiple. where to add this code

Comment: using this code the progress is not showing and no photo is uploading .

Comment: if i remove '});' then progress is showing but single photo is uploaded

Comment: this code block is just to have an idea **how it works** not for **copy paste** . i do not have your plugin, i do not have your code, and environment. the idea is clear, i guess it is enough..

Comment: just  download in the link above and help me out please

Answer (score 0):

After successful upload, use this

```
header ("location: YOUR-PAGE.php");
return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.href = 'new url'` in your upload complete callback (`fileuploaddone`). Read [API](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options) for more on callbacks.

Comment: how to add it please help  me, where to add give the full code , redirect should be done after all multiple photos have been uploaded. Some codes i use redirects after one upload . When i use ur code no progress shows and no uploads done .